# Python and ControlDesk interaction

Tags: python, matlab, simulink

I hope someone can help us.
We are using a dSpace 1103 out of Simulink/Matlab and ControlDesk.

What I would like to know is, is it possible to use python in ControlDesk to transfer data into the dSpace from network? I mean, write an UDP Listener in python and use that script to update variables inside the Simulink/Matlab model?
Or is there any other good chance to transfer data from a program into ControlDesk such that the changes are send to dSpace?

Another question is, how long does it normally take if I change a variable in ControlDesk that the change is done inside dSpace (1-2 ms)??
Is this completely stochastic or more or less a constant value?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is quite possible. You should take a look at "Real-Time Testing" document which you can find in your dSPACE installation directory.

Comment: Thanks, I did this the whole friday. The examples from dSpace are using another library which has to be bought. In the cdautomationlib I didn't found my variable to change. Have you already done this? Do you know something about the delay?